# TCDL Engine doesn't work after migrate to Web 8

Tags: web8, componentpresentation, tcdl, rel

Recently we migrated Tridion from 2011SP1 to Web 8, and noticed when publish a page witha simply embedded component presetation, the TCDL tag and the component presentation rendering result are both printed on the page:

Which triggeres 500 server error when accessing the page as it said the tcdl:ComponentPresentation tag is not recognized(we are using ASP.NET by the way).

After double checked our deployer service and the cd_deployer_conf.xml, I can see the tcdl.dotnet.style setting is there, which should be used to perform the TCDL tag convert from what I understand.

```
<TCDLEngine>
    <Properties>
        <!-- Default code generation will always be targetted towards the use of tag libraries and
            server controls. Uncomment these lines to drop that behaviour -->
        <Property Name="tcdl.dotnet.style" Value="controls"/>
        <Property Name="tcdl.jsp.style" Value="tags"/>

        <!-- Uncomment any of the following lines to set the target language as a specific language -->
        <!--<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="jsp" />-->
        <!--<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="dotnet" />-->
        <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel" />
    </Properties>
    <!-- Optional configuration needed in case of using the UGC TCDL transformers -->

    <TagBundle Resource="ugc_tag_bundle.xml"/>

</TCDLEngine>
```

Can anyone who experenced the similar issue bring me some tips or potential cause of the issue?

Very appriciate your helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you applied the Cumulative Update and the latest hotfixes on top of the installation?

REL DCPs with ASP.NET website were causing issues. Before Web 8, the target language was controlled with the Publication Target and the deployer. In Web 8, publication targets vanished and you could only control the language via the Deployer.

To overcome this issue and to let you control the page language a new property `tcdl.page.target.language` was introduced in the cd_deployer_conf. This property is only available after you apply the latest hotfixes.

Please reach out to Customer Support for more information about the hotfix.

Comment: @SeanEleven, can you please mark the post as answer then ;)

Comment: @Kunal is it tcdl_conf or cd_deployer_conf  we are using web 8.5